# visual studio 2012 build uses unittest frame work 10.0->fail

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

We are using TFS build server having VS 2012 and the team project has unit tests. Previously we had 2010 and all went fine. We reinstalled the server and now we are using VS2012. When unit tests starts in build (according to buildlog) MSTest.exe is executed under visual studio 10 folder. Unit tests fail to start - no errors in log but it just hangs.

If I manually run the command (snippet from log file) and replace folder with visual studio 11 the unit tests are executed.

Why is VS 2012 utilizing 10 version of mstest? all other VS executables utilized are of 11 version? 
'Where `mstest.exe`' says its under 11 folder in the same server.

Why there is visual studio 10 folder - we havenot installed version 10 in this server?

In unit test projects, correct unittest frame work is referenced (under VS 11 folder) - but they also appear to have version 10.0.0 according to the properties.

**Build server log has:**

---

The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

**The following information was included with the event:**

```
(MSTest.exe, PID 3324, Thread 10) DIA initialization threw:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B86AE24D-BF2F-4AC9-B5A2-34B14E4CE11D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.DiaHelper.GetSymbolsFileName(String imagePath)

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

---

(

```
QTAgent32.exe, PID 3780, Thread 12) Received exception calling Adapter.AbortTestRun: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterConverter.Convert(Object value, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue(String name, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.SerializationHelper.GetField(Type fieldType, Object defaultValue)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.SerializationHelper.GetField[T]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestResult..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestResultAggregation..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestResult..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

---